# How to replace a thread when finished

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, queue

I have some code:

```
from threading import Thread
queue = []
for x in range(5):
    queue.append(Thread(target=somefunction))
    queue[x].start()
while True:
    for x in range(5):
        if not queue[x].isAlive():
            queue[x] = Thread(target=someotherfunction)
            queue[x].start()
            #for some reason, this code does not work and 
            #iterates through the loop a lot
```

I was thinking of adding a Queue, but as I saw in the docs, I don't think it's suited to what I want. What I *do* want is to replace a thread in the list if it has finished. If not, do not replace it.

Just a reminder, this is only some pseudo code.
This code is actually suited for a multi-segment downloader.
As a sidenote, this is Python 3.

Comment: A queue would work by writing a wrapper for `somefunction` that manages the queue. However, `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` does the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: @tdelaney Could you evaluate on that, like, for example, show some code?